# Enable adding a model field choices to Django admin dashboard and also be able to add or delete the choices

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

The normal way of interacting with a django model is by using `admin.site.register(my_model)` in `admin.py` file.

If you want to enforce model's field validation you use the `choices` field option like this in `models.py` file.

```
from django.db import models

MY_CHOICES=[
('A','choice 1'),
('B','choice 2'),
('C','choice 3'),

....

]

class MY_MODEL(models.Model):
      ....Some other fields/columns....
      
      options=models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=MY_CHOICES)
```

How would I go about displaying the choices in the admin dashboard and also be able to add new types of choices?

Also, is it possible to enforce validation by importing values from the database as field options?

I tried having another model that will be a table containing the value and descriptions columns.

```
class MY_CHOICES_MODEL(models.Model):
      
      value=models.CharField(max_length=2,..)
      descriptions=models.TextFeild(blank=False)
```

Trying to pass this around to another models field options is the challenge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use foreign key concept like this

````py
from django.db import models

class Choice(models.Model):
      key = models.CharField(max_length=16)
      value = models.CharField(max_length=2)

class MY_MODEL(models.Model):
      ....Some other fields/columns....
      options=models.ForeignKey(Choice, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)```
````

Comment: Thank you. It worked! I will work on model validation with this when posting data